# Can you omit "do you" in question?

Tags: questions

Is the second sentence correct?

1. Do you have a question about XYZ? Contact us!
2. Have a question about XYZ? Contact us!

Basically I wonder if I can omit **do you** or if it is always required.

Comment: The second sentence is grammatically incorrect, because it misses the subject ("you"), but is commonly used in spoken English.

Comment: It is also very commonly omitted in advertising, where brevity is critical.

Comment: More naturally in modern English (especially, in *advertising* contexts) - ***Got** a problem? We can help!*, not ***Have** a problem?* Relatively speaking, ***have*** is more "formal" in such contexts, so it's more jarring when juxtaposed with the [highly colloquial] omission of both subject *and* "helper verb".

Comment: It's fairly common in spoken/informal English. You can go even further and omit the verb too:  Any questions?

Answer (score 0):

In Latin, as well as most languages derived from Latin, the subject is not commonly used because the declension of the verb is based on the subject. Even though this is not true in English, there are many people who are accustomed to it.

The sentence also makes enough sense to be understood without the subject, so it is done often enough despite being formally incorrect.

Comment: Please edit this answer to only include relevant information. Latin has nothing to do with the question or the answer.